# Can't publish *.aab package to Google Play Console from Azure Pipeline. #[error]Error: Failed to upload the bundle *.aab ... reason: socket hang up

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, yaml, google-play-console, azure-pipelines-yaml

Azure Pipeline, GooglePlayRelease@4 task, Unable to upload to Google play Console from Azure pipeline.

`##[error]Error: Failed to upload the bundle D:/a/1/a/xxx.xxx.xxxx.aab. Failed with message: FetchError: request to... ...reason: socket hang up`

I am unable to publish my signed *.aab package to my Google Play Console from an Azure Pipeline. I have been struggling over this the past couple of days.

My Azure pipeline builds my project, creates an *.aab package, signs it and publishes it successfully. But publishing to the Google Play Console fails with the error detail shown below.

I can take the published .aab and upload it to Google Play manually to confirm the package is valid ie. signed. I then delete it from Google Play Console. This is shown in the image further on.

```
1.  Starting: GooglePlayRelease 
============================================================================== 
Task : Google Play - Release 
Description : Release an app to the Google Play Store 
Version : 4.235.0 
Author : Microsoft Corporation 
Help : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play 
============================================================================== 
Authenticated with Google Play and getting new edit 
##[error]Error: Failed to upload the bundle D:/a/1/a/xxx.xxx.xxxx.aab. Failed with message: FetchError: request to https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/xxx.xxx.xxxx/edits/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/bundles?uploadType=media failed, reason: socket hang up 
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\a\_tasks\GooglePlayRelease_xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx\4.235.0\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1491:11) 
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:35) 
at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:519:9) 
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35) 
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1408:12) 
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) { 
type: 'system', 
errno: 'ECONNRESET', 
code: 'ECONNRESET', 
config: [Object] 
}. 
Finishing: GooglePlayRelease
```

`Authenticated with Google Play and getting new edit`

My assumption here with this line, is that my user connection successfully authenticates successfully and ready for upload to google play?

My Azure YAML, I download the package published in the previous stage.
I can 'ls' it to confirm the package is available and can see the file size.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'
variables:
  androidPackageName: xxx.xxx.xxx
 
….
 
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
  buildType: 'current'        
  buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
  downloadType: 'single'
           
  - script: |
     echo "2 $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(androidPackageName).aab:" '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(androidPackageName).aab'
     ls -l '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(androidPackageName).aab'
 
- task: GooglePlayRelease@4
  inputs: 
  serviceConnection: ServiceConnectionName
  applicationId: $(androidPackageName) 
  action: 'SingleBundle'
  bundleFile: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(androidPackageName).aab''
  track: 'internal'
```

The first Job in my pipeline publishes the artifacts.

[Artifact published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi6Ji.png)

I can successfully upload this artifact manually to Google Play to confirm it is signed etc.

[Manual upload to Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Api5.png)

A more verbose log of a subsequent pipeline run.

```
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6345494Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'GooglePlayRelease'
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6346398Z ##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6346651Z ##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6347103Z ##[debug]=> True
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6347360Z ##[debug]Result: True
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6347629Z ##[section]Starting: GooglePlayRelease
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6467666Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6467810Z Task         : Google Play - Release
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6467897Z Description  : Release an app to the Google Play Store
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6467990Z Version      : 4.235.0
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6468054Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6468142Z Help         : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6468257Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-05T08:57:02.6924712Z ##[debug]Using node path: C:\agents\3.232.3\externals\node20_1\bin\node.exe
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5685865Z ##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=D:\a\_temp
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5686354Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5686765Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_8d9e1e9b-7a3d-4de9-97e8-7be4603edf2e
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5687215Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_8d9e1e9b-7a3d-4de9-97e8-7be4603edf2e_PASSWORD
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5687692Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_8d9e1e9b-7a3d-4de9-97e8-7be4603edf2e_USERNAME
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5688143Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5688581Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_8d9e1e9b-7a3d-4de9-97e8-7be4603edf2e
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5688991Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5689393Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5689769Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ACTION
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5690136Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_APPLICATIONID
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5690511Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_AUTHTYPE
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5690862Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_BUNDLEFILE
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5691231Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CHANGELOGFILE
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5740685Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CHANGESNOTSENTFORREVIEW
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5741161Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CHANGEUPDATEPRIORITY
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5741815Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ISDRAFTRELEASE
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5742178Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_LANGUAGECODE
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5742555Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_METADATAROOTPATH
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5742945Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_RELEASENOTESCONTAINLANGUAGETAGS
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5743347Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_RESCUECHANGESNOTSENTFORREVIEW
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5743738Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ROLLOUTTOUSERFRACTION
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5744123Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SERVICEACCOUNTKEY
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5744487Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SERVICEENDPOINT
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5744866Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SHOULDATTACHMETADATA
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5745254Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SHOULDPICKOBBFILE
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5745637Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SHOULDUPLOADMAPPINGFILE
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5746024Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SHOULDUPLOADMAPPINGFILES
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5746409Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SHOULDUPLOADNATIVEDEBUGSYMBOLFILES
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5746877Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SHOULDUPLOADNATIVEDEBUGSYMBOLS
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5747263Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TRACK
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5747630Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_UPDATEPRIORITY
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5748001Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_USERFRACTION
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5748365Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_VERSIONCODEFILTERTYPE
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5748752Z ##[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5749114Z ##[debug]loaded 33
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5749466Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5749830Z ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5750185Z ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.5750563Z ##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9777302Z ##[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\GooglePlayRelease_8cf7cac0-620b-11e5-b4cf-8565e60f4d27\4.235.0\task.json
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9782507Z ##[debug]adding resource file: D:\a\_tasks\GooglePlayRelease_8cf7cac0-620b-11e5-b4cf-8565e60f4d27\4.235.0\task.json
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9783184Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9799575Z ##[debug]Prepare task inputs.
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9806992Z ##[debug]authType=ServiceEndpoint
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9809275Z ##[debug]serviceEndpoint=8d9e1e9b-7a3d-4de9-97e8-7be4603edf2e
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9811849Z ##[debug]8d9e1e9b-7a3d-4de9-97e8-7be4603edf2e exists true
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9815266Z ##[debug]action=SingleBundle
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9815826Z ##[debug]Action: SingleBundle
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9816854Z ##[debug]applicationId=com.xxx.xxx
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9817373Z ##[debug]Application identifier: com.xxx.xxx
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9821675Z ##[debug]bundleFile=D:\a\1\a/com.xxx.xxx.aab
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9859956Z ##[debug]Bundles: D:/a/1/a/com.xxx.xxx.aab
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9860609Z ##[debug]APKs: 
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9861920Z ##[debug]shouldPickObbFile=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9863449Z ##[debug]track=internal
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9866809Z ##[debug]shouldAttachMetadata=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9868615Z ##[debug]changelogFile=D:\a\1\s
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9869827Z ##[debug]languageCode=en-US
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9871092Z ##[debug]releaseNotesContainLanguageTags=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9872337Z ##[debug]changeUpdatePriority=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9874335Z ##[debug]rolloutToUserFraction=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9876234Z ##[debug]shouldUploadMappingFile=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9876758Z ##[debug]mappingFilePath=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9877815Z ##[debug]shouldUploadNativeDebugSymbols=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9878343Z ##[debug]nativeDebugSymbolsFile=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9879398Z ##[debug]shouldUploadMappingFiles=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9880819Z ##[debug]shouldUploadNativeDebugSymbolFiles=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9881980Z ##[debug]changesNotSentForReview=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9882568Z ##[debug]changesNotSentForReview: false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9887599Z ##[debug]rescueChangesNotSentForReview=false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9888258Z ##[debug]rescueChangesNotSentForReview: false
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9889433Z ##[debug]releaseName=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9889998Z ##[debug]versionCodeFilterType=all
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9890466Z ##[debug]Checking if unused input apkFile is set...
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9890903Z ##[debug]apkFile=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9891355Z ##[debug]Checking if unused input bundleFiles is set...
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9891808Z ##[debug]bundleFiles=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9892262Z ##[debug]Checking if unused input apkFiles is set...
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9892708Z ##[debug]apkFiles=undefined
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9893138Z ##[debug]Updating Global Parameters
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9893596Z ##[debug]SETTING packageName TO "com.xxx.xxx"
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9894122Z ##[debug]Global Params set to {"auth":null,"params":{"packageName":"com.xxx.xxx"}}
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9894604Z ##[debug]Initializing JWT.
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9895093Z ##[debug]Initializing Google Play publisher API.
2024-02-05T08:57:04.9895538Z ##[debug]Authorize JWT.
2024-02-05T08:57:05.3628942Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setsecret]***
2024-02-05T08:57:05.3637517Z Authenticated with Google Play and getting new edit
2024-02-05T08:57:05.3638473Z ##[debug]Creating a new edit transaction in Google Play.
2024-02-05T08:57:05.3639171Z ##[debug]Creating a new edit
2024-02-05T08:57:05.3639732Z ##[debug]Additional Parameters: {"packageName":"com.xxx.xxx"}
2024-02-05T08:57:05.4598472Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75473.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 31.71
2024-02-05T08:57:05.9330348Z ##[debug]Updating Global Parameters
2024-02-05T08:57:05.9332023Z ##[debug]SETTING editId TO "08305314830395948005"
2024-02-05T08:57:05.9340056Z ##[debug]Global Params set to {"auth":{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0,"transporter":{},"credentials":{"access_token":"***","token_type":"Bearer","expiry_date":1707127023000,"refresh_token":"jwt-placeholder"},"eagerRefreshThresholdMillis":300000,"forceRefreshOnFailure":false,"certificateCache":{},"certificateExpiry":null,"certificateCacheFormat":"PEM","refreshTokenPromises":{},"email":"***","keyFile":null,"key":"***","scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"],"subject":null,"gtoken":{"keyFile":null,"key":"***","rawToken":{"access_token":"***","expires_in":3599,"token_type":"Bearer"},"iss":"***","sub":null,"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher","expiresAt":1707127023000}},"params":{"packageName":"com.xxx.xxx","editId":"08305314830395948005"}}
2024-02-05T08:57:05.9341233Z ##[debug]Uploading 1 AAB(s).
2024-02-05T08:57:05.9341626Z ##[debug]Uploading bundle D:/a/1/a/com.xxx.xxx.aab
2024-02-05T08:57:05.9342444Z ##[debug]Request Parameters: {"packageName":"com.xxx.xxx","media":{"body":{"fd":null,"path":"D:/a/1/a/com.xxx.xxx.aab","flags":"r","mode":438,"end":null,"bytesRead":0,"_readableState":{"state":6176,"highWaterMark":65536,"buffer":{"head":null,"tail":null,"length":0},"length":0,"pipes":[],"flowing":null,"errored":null,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","awaitDrainWriters":null,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"_events":{},"_eventsCount":1},"mimeType":"application/octet-stream"}}
2024-02-05T08:57:10.4708107Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75473.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 24.21
2024-02-05T08:57:15.4724019Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75473.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 19.55
2024-02-05T08:57:20.4856552Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75473.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 16.39
2024-02-05T08:57:25.5092640Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75473.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 14.19
2024-02-05T08:57:30.5222405Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 12.45
2024-02-05T08:57:35.5334656Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 11.10
2024-02-05T08:57:40.5467973Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 10.01
2024-02-05T08:57:45.5717028Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 9.11
2024-02-05T08:57:50.5781159Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 8.36
2024-02-05T08:57:55.5913687Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 7.73
2024-02-05T08:58:00.6002176Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 7.21
2024-02-05T08:58:05.6102502Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 6.73
2024-02-05T08:58:10.6110110Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 6.32
2024-02-05T08:58:15.6353907Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 5.95
2024-02-05T08:58:20.6469100Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75469.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 5.62
2024-02-05T08:58:25.6494910Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 5.33
2024-02-05T08:58:30.6504969Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 5.07
2024-02-05T08:58:35.6561940Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 4.83
2024-02-05T08:58:40.6623440Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 4.61
2024-02-05T08:58:45.6658563Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 4.41
2024-02-05T08:58:50.6741267Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 4.23
2024-02-05T08:58:55.6851304Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 4.09
2024-02-05T08:59:00.7039340Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 3.93
2024-02-05T08:59:06.2086351Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 3.77
2024-02-05T08:59:11.2186120Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 3.64
2024-02-05T08:59:16.2357773Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 3.51
2024-02-05T08:59:21.2404315Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 3.41
2024-02-05T08:59:26.2527496Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 3.30
2024-02-05T08:59:31.2682134Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 3.20
2024-02-05T08:59:36.2718112Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 3.10
2024-02-05T08:59:41.2778111Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 3.01
2024-02-05T08:59:46.2864441Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.93
2024-02-05T08:59:51.2969042Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.85
2024-02-05T08:59:56.3111728Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.78
2024-02-05T09:00:01.3121242Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.70
2024-02-05T09:00:06.3278348Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.64
2024-02-05T09:00:11.3362577Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.57
2024-02-05T09:00:16.3455152Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75461.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.51
2024-02-05T09:00:21.3463960Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75445.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.45
2024-02-05T09:00:26.3519699Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75445.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.39
2024-02-05T09:00:31.3576883Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75445.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.34
2024-02-05T09:00:36.3609679Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75445.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.29
2024-02-05T09:00:41.3690823Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75445.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.24
2024-02-05T09:00:46.3751820Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75445.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.19
2024-02-05T09:00:51.3780978Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75445.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.14
2024-02-05T09:00:56.3922017Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75445.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.10
2024-02-05T09:01:01.4054058Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk:C:\ Windows available:75445.00MB out of 261643.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 7167MB, CPU: usage 2.06
2024-02-05T09:01:05.9589129Z ##[debug]Failed to upload the bundle "D:/a/1/a/com.xxx.xxx.aab"
2024-02-05T09:01:05.9590503Z ##[debug]FetchError: request to https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.xxx.xxx/edits/08305314830395948005/bundles?uploadType=media failed, reason: socket hang up
2024-02-05T09:01:05.9635432Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2024-02-05T09:01:05.9673927Z ##[error]Error: Failed to upload the bundle D:/a/1/a/com.xxx.xxx.aab. Failed with message: FetchError: request to https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.xxx.xxx/edits/08305314830395948005/bundles?uploadType=media failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\a\_tasks\GooglePlayRelease_8cf7cac0-620b-11e5-b4cf-8565e60f4d27\4.235.0\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1491:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:519:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1408:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  config: [Object]
}.
2024-02-05T09:01:05.9686271Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Failed to upload the bundle D:/a/1/a/com.xxx.xxx.aab. Failed with message: FetchError: request to https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.xxx.xxx/edits/08305314830395948005/bundles?uploadType=media failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\a\_tasks\GooglePlayRelease_8cf7cac0-620b-11e5-b4cf-8565e60f4d27\4.235.0\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1491:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:519:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1408:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  config: [Object]
}.
2024-02-05T09:01:05.9697900Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Failed to upload the bundle D:/a/1/a/com.xxx.xxx.aab. Failed with message: FetchError: request to https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.xxx.xxx/edits/08305314830395948005/bundles?uploadType=media failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\a\_tasks\GooglePlayRelease_8cf7cac0-620b-11e5-b4cf-8565e60f4d27\4.235.0\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1491:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:519:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1408:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  config: [Object]
}.
2024-02-05T09:01:05.9826456Z ##[section]Finishing: GooglePlayRelease
```

My service account is set up, linked to Google Play console with admin permissions.
With the service account key, I have set up a Service Connection in Azure with the private key from the json file created when the service account key was created.

[Service Account user assigned to Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWGEU.png)

[Service Account permissions has admin on Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9slf.png)

[Service Account key set up, JSON file in possession](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpoGr.png)

[Private Key from JSON file, in Service Connection set up on Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qhKy.png)

[I can see authentication metrics after running my Azure pipeline on the Google Service Account for the key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D4Ur.png)

Comment: In your task log, Bundle path is `D:/a/1/a/xxx.xxx.xxxx.aab` , it is `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)`, while in yaml, you used  `$(Pipeline.Workspace) `, it's `D:/a/1` without another `a`. Also task `DownloadBuildArtifacts@1` will download file to arifact folder by default. Please correct the yaml. In addition, after you unload the pacakge munally to google play store, please don't delete it.

Comment: I've updated the YAML. I have tried both $(Pipeline.Workspace), $(System.ArtifactsDirectory) for the bundleFile in the task, it gave the same error in both cases. To clarify after uploading the package to Play Console, I delete it from the play console and then rerun the task as it would publish the same bundle. However, I have run the pipeline several times creating new artifacts to publish with the same failing result. Thanks.

Comment: So your bundle can be published via 1st pipeline, but failed with new artifact in the latter pipeline? May i know what changed between the two builds?

Comment: I have not yet published the bundle from a pipeline. This is my first go and it's failing at the last hurdle. I have added a more more verbose log to the ticket. I am guessing it's a network issue from the Azure agent or permissions. Thanks